# Deleting multiple rows on the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table making a relationship between `CUSTOMER_ID`, and `B_CODE`.
There are multiple instances of `CUSTOMER_ID` having different `B_CODE`. I'm making an UI capable of adding and removing codes from this table based on a swaplist UI. I know how to insert multiple rows in the same query, but I'm not sure of how to do the same when removing.

I know I could just remove all instances of said `CUSTOMER_ID` and then adding what is left on the list. But that seems like a bad way to do it.

So how can I remove multiple rows on that table with the same ID, different codes, in the same query, but without removing all the instances of such ID?

So for example I got this

```
+------------+---------+
| 123        | A       |
| 124        | B       |
| 123        | C       |
| 123        | D       |
| 124        | E       |
| 123        | F       |
+------------+---------+
```

And I only want to delete
`123 -> A`,`123 -> C`, and `123 -> F` but not `123 -> D`, and in the same query.

Comment: Please provide data and expected results, it's easier to help then...

Comment: @MrSimpleMind Sure, formatting is not the best though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94acfb/1)

(a) ***If you want to delete all rows that you know the b_code for:***

```
delete from t where customer_id = 123 and b_code in ('A','C','F');
```

(b) ***Or if you want to delete all rows except the one you know the b_code for***

```
delete from t where customer_id = 123 and b_code not in ('D');
```

> Use (a) if you have few b_codes selected for deletion.
>
> Use (b) if you have few b_codes to keep.

Comment: No, I want to delete some of the rows with a specific customer_id, but not all of them

Comment: @Zerjack see my updated answer, I just saw your edit.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you have a UI that will allow the removal of multiple codes per customer.  I am unsure of what the criteria is of which record to select for preservation.  In you example you choose D.  In an UI scenario I would think that the user would not select D for removal.

To the root question, if I understand correctly, you can use the Row_Number and or Rank to query the records you want to delete.  Because you choose D in your example you can not rely on a simple order by in the window function you may have to have a sort field or a related table to ensure you choose the right 'keeper' record.

Comment: Hmmm.... Honestly I could't understand much of what you said... There's no criteria. Just two listboxes in a swap UI fashion that allow the user to select what to keep and what to remove.

Comment: My point was that you can use row number and or rank along with the customerID to order the rows such that a specific row is chosen as a keeper rather than hard coding the values.  I am not familiar with swapUI and so I assume that it is much simpler that I first thought.